# Finding NIC firmware version

Tags: windows-server-2008, firmware, nic

I need to find out the firmware version of the NIC(s) on  on IBM Windows Server 2008 using CMD, Powershell or by any other means.I also should note that I can't reboot the server to go to bios or use IBM Update Express

Comment: These are Broadcom Netxtreme NICs, all of them are in use.

Comment: The hardware ID (which you can get from the device manager's `Details` tab) may tell you. Some devices put their firmware version in the ID. Look for an `&REV_...` in the ID.

Answer (score 2):

Well this is not native to 2008 that I know of. I would look in the command line utilities provided by the NIC vendors. You will need to have their management software installed to use them.

1. For Broadcom NIC's I would try the "BACScli" command
2. For Intel NIC's I would try the "prosetcl" command

More details on the intel command line tools can be found http://www.intel.com/support/network/sb/CS-029966.htm

These commands might be able to pull the firmware info as their GUI counterparts can display this information. If the commands will pull the data you need, you should be able to use them in a powershell script. And use WinRM or PS (sysinternals) commands to use them remotely if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's hard to do...  Does any of the following look like a firmware version?

Here's what SiSoft Sandra shows on my PC:

```
SiSoftware Sandra

Device Information
Device Type : Ethernet Network
Device ID : Bus 5, Device 0, Function 0
Official Device Name : Broadcom NetXtreme 57xx Gigabit Controller
OEM Device Name : Broadcom NetXtreme BCM5761 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
Hardware ID : VEN_14E4 DEV_1681 REV_10
Device Name : Dell Broadcom NetXtreme 57xx Gigabit Controller
Product ID : VEN_1028 DEV_0293 REV_10
Revision : B1

Power Management Features
Version : 1.02
Supports Clock Slow-down : Yes
Supports D1 PM State : No
Supports D2 PM State : No
Supports PME# : Yes
Supports PME Clock : No

PCIe Capabilities
Version : 2.00
Port : 0
Physical Slot Implemented : No
Phantom Functions Support : No
Maximum Payload Size : 256
Width : x1 / x1
Speed : 2.5Gbps / 2.5Gbps

Device Capabilities
Line Cache Size : 16bytes
I/O Range : No
Memory Range : Yes
Bus Master Capable : Yes
Special Cycle Recognition : No
Memory Write and Invalidate : No
Video Palette Snoop : No
Parity Error Response : No
Address/Data Stepping : No
System Error Line : No
Fast back-to-back Transactions : No
Detects Parity Errors : No
Supports System Error Line : No
Supports Parity Line : No
User Defined Format : No
66MHz Bus Support : No
New Capability List : Yes
Device Select Timing : Fast
Multi-Function Device : No
Header : 00
Interface : 00

Hardware Resources
Memory Range : F5DE0000
Memory Range : F5DF0000
INT Pin : A#
Dynamic Management : Yes
```

Comment: The `REV_10` is either a hardware controller version or a firmware version.

Comment: Sounds like a tech support call to Broadcom is in order.

Comment: Well, it seems like there is no real way to do that. So the only option I could come up with , was to create a DSA log file.

Answer (score 0):

Try in Powershell:

```
Get-NetAdapter | fl name, InterfaceDescription, DriverFileName, DriverDate, DriverVersionString, NdisVersion
```

That will return the DriverVersion and firmware NDiS version.

Example output:

```
name                 : Ethernet 4
InterfaceDescription : Lenovo USB Ethernet
DriverFileName       : dlcdcncm6_x64.sys
DriverDate           : 2013-07-03
DriverVersionString  : 7.3.49014.0
NdisVersion          : 6.20

name                 : Wi-Fi
InterfaceDescription : Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6205
DriverFileName       : NETwew00.sys
DriverDate           : 2012-10-03
DriverVersionString  : 15.5.6.48
NdisVersion          : 6.30
```

Comment: This cmdlet only works on Win8 or Server2012.  OP has Server2008.  http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/752032/cmdlet-get-netadapter  Moreover, your sample output does not show firmware, only driver version

Comment: Oops...true on the cmdlet...I never bother to check for backwards compatibility.  The firmware version I referred to was the NDIS version.  Their might be a way through WMIC, but I'd have to try and load up a w2k8 to check.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Broadcom utility - BACS, change the view to NDIS and highlight the adapter